# Mongoose Virtuals in MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My Mongoose Schema is as follows:

```
var DSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  original_y: {type: Number},,
  new_y: {type: Number},,
  date: {type: Date},
  dummy: [dummyEmbeddedDocuments]
  }, toObject: { virtuals: true }, toJSON: { virtuals: true}
});

DSchema.virtual('dateformatted').get(function () {
 return moment(this.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('D', DSchema);
```

A document in my schema would be the following:

```
{
 id:1,
 original_y: 200,
 new_y: 140,
 date: 2015-05-03 00:00:00.000-18:30,
 dummy: [
  {id:1, storage:2, cost: 10},
  {id:2, storage:0, cost: 20},
  {id:3, storage:5, cost: 30},
  ]
}
```

My Query:

```
Item.aggregate([
{ 
    "$match": {
        "dummy.storage": {"$gt": 0}
    } 
},
{ 
    "$unwind": "$dummy"
},
{
    "$project": {
        "original_y": 1, 
        "new_y": 1,
        "dateformatted": 1,
        "dummy.id": "$dummy.id",
        "dummy.storage": "$dummy.storage",
        "dummy.cost": "$dummy.cost",
        "dummy.tallyAmount": {
            "$divide": [
                { "$add": ["$new_y","$original_y"] },
                "$dummy.cost"
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "_$id",
        "original_y": { "$first": "$original_y" },
        "dateformatted": { "$first": "$dateformatted" },
        "new_y": { "$first": "$new_y" },
        "dummy": {
            "$addToSet": "$dummy"
        }
    }        
}
]).exec(callback);
```

This query however returns the **VIRTUAL** dateformatted attribute as NULL. Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple notes in [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) touch on why this is so:

> - Arguments are not cast to the model's schema because `$project` operators allow redefining the "shape" of the documents at any stage
>     of the pipeline, which may leave documents in an incompatible format.
> - The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned).

But it goes beyond this because the `aggregate` operation is performed server-side, where any client-side Mongoose concepts like virtuals do not exist.

The result is that you'll need to include the `date` field in your `$project` and `$group` stages and add your own `dateformatted` field to the results in code based on the `date` values.

Comment: `The documents returned are plain javascript objects` Does it mean I can't use virtual fields and mongoose's methods for documents returned by aggregation framework query?

Comment: Actually, this is one of the reasons why mongoose is garbage.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question but I've come up with a useful hack to get back the virtuals and thought it might be useful for those searching for this problem.

You can easily convert the objects back to mongoose models:

```
documents = documents.map(d => {
  return new Document(d);
});

var virtual = documents[0].virtualProperty;
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified it slightly to populate virtuals by calling `.toJSON()`. 
`documents.map(d => new Document(d).toJSON())`

Comment: Mongoose should perform that internally, but unfortunately it's not.

Comment: Please use `Model.hydrate(doc);` instead.

Comment: @Epple You should provide reasoning

Comment: @bendataclear The `hydrate` method is built-in mongoose to help solve this issue, so you just use it

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works!
Aggregate queries return js objects which is not an instance of mongoose Document.
You may use [Model.hydrate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.hydrate)

```bash
const documents = docs.map(doc => myModel.hydrate(doc))
```

Answer (score 0):

the `<field>: <1 or true>` form is used to include an existing field which is not the case here since the `dateformatted` field doesn't exist and you have to create it using an expression, [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) can be used:

```
"$project": {
  "original_y": 1, 
  "new_y": 1,
  "dateformatted": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "date": "$date" } },
  ...
```

Another option is to use it with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields):

```
{
  "$project": {
    ...
  }
},
{
  "$addFields": {
    "dateformatted": { "$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "date": "$date"} }
  }
},
...
```