# mongoose schema methods in aggregates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, aggregate

how can access methods in aggregates ?

```
let
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let
    UserSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        lastname: String
    });


UserSchema.methods.fullname = () => {
    return this.name + " " + this.lastname;
};

let
    UserModel = mongoose.model("user",UserSchema);


let 
    query = [
        {
            $match: {
                "name": /foo/i
            }
        }
    ];

UserModel.aggregate(query, (err, users) => {
    if(err) throw new Error(err);

    for(let user of users){
        console.log(user.fullname());
    }

});
```

and result

```
TypeError: user.fullname is not a function
```

i can use this

```
UserModel.findOne(query, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw new Error(err);

    console.log(user.fullname());

});
```

result

```
foo bar
```

but i need get other params in aggregate for my real query ( $addFields, $lookup, $filters, and other)

thx =D

Comment: [I don't think you can unfortunately.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30042373/1022914)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Virtuals in MongoDB Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038855/mongoose-virtuals-in-mongodb-aggregate)

Comment: I'm not using $project only $aggregate ... $aggregate creates a virtual $project auto?